# Optimization of node_modules files in angular 4 with ASP.Net MVC, Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, asp.net-mvc, angular, visual-studio

I am using angular 4 in Visual studio 2017 with ASP.Net MVC. I tried to bundle all the files that required to load the page. E.g

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css")
                .Include(
                          "~/Assets/css/LoaderCss.css",
                          "~/Assets/css/style.css",
                          "~/Assets/css/responsive.css"
                          ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/script/scripts")
                .Include(
                          "~/" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JsConfiguration"],
                          "~/Assets/script/jquery.min.js",
                          "~/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js",
                          "~/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js",
                         "~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js",
                         "~/systemjs.config.js"
                          ));


            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        }
```

and used on _LayoutPage.cshtml

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
   @Scripts.Render("~/script/scripts")
```

But while loading the page all the required modules/files start loading that makes home page little slow. its because delay loading. e.g

[image]

Any idea how we can optimize this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should start observing the elements, which of them is taking longer. Sometimes a "big" sized file can cause the delay.

For Prototypjs framework.
You may use

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    // do something here
});
```

from  [Prototype API documentation](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/document/observe/).

For node.js
https://www.npmjs.com/package/observe

You may even use DeveloperTools in detail to find the "problematic" files.